# Ringing in OPamp OutPut

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise, wheatstone-bridge, signal-to-noise, ringing

I am using this Differential In/Out Opamp circuit as ADC driver and to provide some gain(G=6.4).

The component values are R53,R52=100, C28, C27=1.1uF, R56= 1K, R57=open, R55,R54= 2K7, U6=[OPA2211](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sbos377g/sbos377g.pdf).

[image]

At ADC input I have simple RC filter.
[image]

Component Values are C10,C11=Open, C7=1uF, R26, R27=100.

Now the problem I am facing is My opamp output seems to have some noise like this,
[image]

But as I expanded the time scale I saw this,
[image]

I don't understand where this is coming from, I powered my ckt with linear supply but saw no improvement. Sensor connected to OPamp Inputs is a wheatstone bridge Pressure sensor and it looks cleans. kindly help me.

**Edit:** I am using MCP1640 Boost converter to get 5v from 1 cell Liion.
And using MCP1702 to get 3.3 V from 5V.
I thought it was switching noise but I also tried with Linear supply.

Comment: What's the peak to peak voltage of these spikes?

Comment: 120mV................................

Comment: The first image shows 40mV and the second shows 120mV. Which one shall we pick?

Comment: Hmm Even I don't understand it. consider 120mv one.

Comment: Anyway, what are the voltage regulators used in your circuit? please write their part numbers.

Comment: Actually the biggest spike is not getting captured in 25us time scale so you see the smaller ones in that.

Comment: What's the frequency of the biggest spike? Did you make proper power supply decoupling for the OPAMPs, the MCU and any other IC in your circuit? How are you filtering your Analog GND from the noise on the Digital GND?

Comment: Yea i placed multiple caps from 1 uf to 0.001uf which removed the spike from supply rail, but it is still there in opamp output.

Comment: Can you post your board layout? You should pay attention to the placement of decoupling caps to be as close as possible to the supply pins. Also filtering DGND and AGND and making sure that no digital signal crosses AGND and vice versa is important. That's why I am asking for the layout.

Answer (score 3):

I found the culprit.
Actually it is due to ADC's switching when it takes Sample. I disconnected OPamp's Output from ADC by removing the R from RC and the ringing was gone.

Comment: Does proper decoupling of the op amp and adc fix this?

Comment: No it has nothing to do with decoupling.
When ADC's switch closes to take the sample(i.e. charge ADC's Internal sampling capacitor) then there is a disturbance in signal path.
Increasing value of Resistance did suppress it a bit, but it is still there.

Answer (score 0):

The 0.1uF is a too high value to be driven by the opamp. Remove them, or replace by pF capacitors. Ampops naturally use to be unstable when driving capacitive loads. The best thing to do is build the filters at the input or feedback traces.

Comment: "Ampops" is a new one, Jair. Welcome to EE.SE.